# Clean URL in local host

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, localhost

I am currently trying to clean URL in my local machine(wamp) before using that(.htaccess) script in my online website. This is my localhost address

```
  http://localhost/index.php
  http://localhost/people.php
  http://localhost/current.php
```

i want to clean this url to

```
  http://localhost/home/
  http://localhost/People/
  http://localhost/Current/
```

respectively. But for start(and also for easy) i want to change only **index.php** file to **home** . i found this script while searching web

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [NC,L]
```

but when i tried this script in my local machine nothing worked,still my url is showing like this

```
 http://localhost/index.php
```

i dont know where i went wrong, can any one help me..

Comment: Did you type `localhost/home/` in the browser window? The original file name is still conserved you know.

Comment: yes, thanks truth i have misunderstood the concept of rewriting.once more thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have some sort of misconception over how rewriting works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This means that if the URL (which was typed in the browser) matches the first argument (`^home/?$`), that request should be rewritten to `index.php`.

What you should do, is instead of trying to get to type `index.php` in the browser bar, type `http://localhost/home/`. You should see the index page, even though the browser address bar says `/home/`.

Comment: yep! your are correct i misunderstood the rewriting concept. so in my website files the hyperlink to my index.php (HOME button) should change from index.php to /home/

Answer (score 1):

Open up .htaccess and insert the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -multiviews

RewriteRule ^home/$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^People/$ people.php [L]
RewriteRule ^Current/$ current.php [L]
```

Then go to your website URL and do: /home/ (and /People/ /Current/)